# fetching only values that does not contain a particular value in any of its row

Tags: sql, oracle

my requirement was to list all prescriptions done by the doctors who at least one time prescribed the drugs supplied by
the company kleen. List a name of doctor, drug name, patient
name, and date of prescription.

so for example if the data stored within the database was like this

```
CREATE TABLE DOCTOR (
    DID         VARCHAR2(20)
        CONSTRAINT Doctor_DID_NotNull NOT NULL,
    DName       VARCHAR2(50),
    Speciality      VARCHAR2(70),
    YearOfExp       Number,
CONSTRAINT Doctor_PK PRIMARY KEY (DID)
);

CREATE TABLE PATIENT (
    PID         VARCHAR2(20)
        CONSTRAINT   PATIENT_PID_NotNull NOT NULL,
    PName       VARCHAR2(50),
    PDOB            DATE,
    PAddress        VARCHAR2(70),
    PPostalcode     VARCHAR2(12),
    FamilyDoctor        VARCHAR2(20),
CONSTRAINT Patient_PK PRIMARY KEY (PID),
CONSTRAINT Patient_FK FOREIGN KEY (FamilyDoctor) REFERENCES DOCTOR (DID)
);
```

And this was what I had used to fetch the data

```
SELECT dr.DName, pr.Tradename, pa.PName, pr.PrescDT
FROM PRESCRIPTION pr, DOCTOR dr, PATIENT pa
WHERE pr.PharName ='kleen'
AND pr.DID = dr.DID
AND pr.PID = pa.PID;
```

But it only return to me saying that no rows were selected. How do i phrase it then, such that I will get the results that I want.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Probably a data issue. What records do you have in PRESCRIPTION  where  `pr.PharName ='kleen'`? My guess is none. Perhaps you have records for `'KLEEN'` or `'Kleen'`, maybe you have no records at all.

Comment: @APC, in my opinion is right.  Consider `UPPER(PharName) = 'KLEEN'`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I correctly understood your question but I think you can try following query. Pls try to post sample data and desired output (text formatted). Contact for any problem.

```
SELECT dr.DName, pr.Tradename, pa.PName, pr.PrescDT
FROM DOCTOR dr
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT dr.DID
    FROM PRESCRIPTION pr
    INNER JOIN DOCTOR dr ON pr.DID = dr.DID
    WHERE pr.PharName ='kleen') dr2 ON dr.DID = dr2.DID
INNER JOIN  PRESCRIPTION pr ON pr.DID = dr.DID
INNER JOIN PATIENT pa ON  pr.PID = pa.PID
;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the patient table, familydoctor is the column name which is referencing to the doctor table, so try as

```
SELECT dr.dname, 
       pr.tradename, 
       pa.pname, 
       pr.prescdt 
FROM   prescription pr 
       JOIN doctor dr 
         ON ( pr.did = dr.did ) 
       JOIN patient pa 
         ON ( dr.did = pa.familydoctor) 
WHERE  LOWER(pr.pharname) = LOWER('kleen');
```

If needed add `LEFT OUTER JOIN` or `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` as per your requirement.

Ideally, you should provide columns and sample data for all three tables, then it would be better to analyse the problem.

Comment: Actually, I think your join between doctor and patient is incorrect.  The join would be between prescriber and patient, which I think OP had correct, but OP did not provide DDL for prescriber table.  A prescription has two references, one to the doctor that wrote it and one to the patient is it for, which may or may not be the patient's family doctor.

Comment: @unleashed My join is based on the relationship which OP is mentioned in the question where `familydoctor` is referenced to `did`.

Comment: I see that now.  I understand the connection.  But, having some experience with pharmacy, although that does indeed relate to a doctor, it is not in the context of a prescription, only to designate the family doctor (or sometimes called a primary doctor).